# Convert from hexadecimal integer to decimal java

Tags: java, hex, decimal, number-systems

There are pre-translated numbers from hexadecimal to decimal. For example, 0x01, 0x10 and so on. I need to extract from it everything that is after x, so that I get a number that could fit as an index to the array.

The difficulty lies in the fact that the hex value is an Integer (NOT AS a String), that is, it is in this format:

```
int hexValue = 16; // 0x10
```

And I need to get the answer 10.

Why is this necessary? I need the hexadecimal value to be a full-fledged index for the array

Comment: `String.valueOf(n)` Um, if `n` is your input, it already is "decimal."  Just use it.

Comment: those 2 things don't do the same thing. In fact, I'm not sure your second function does anything at all?

Comment: @markspace changed the post

Comment: It's still decimal.  The `0x` part does the conversion for you.  In other words if you print that value it'll print "16".

Comment: @markspace I know, but I don't specify the number in advance, I don't know it

Comment: You're not making any sense.  I think you'll most likely need to clarify what your input is, but if it's a "number" then it's just a number and decimal or hex doesn't matter until you choose to print it.  Numbers internally are all the same.

Comment: Hexadecimal and decimal as well as binary are just different representations of the same number. You cannot convert from an *hexadecimal int* to a *decimal int* because there is no such thing as a *hexadecimal int* or *decimal int*. There is only one `int` datatype which will be stored in binary, the rest is just how it's represented as a String.

Comment: Here is a 100% correct line of code that will take `int hex = 0x10` and properly give you the value of that in hexadecimal.  This line of code is _absolutely correct_ and will be correct for all inputs.  Here it is: `int decimal = hex;`  I can even guarantee that it'll be extremely efficient, and a proper benchmark will show you that it takes zero nanoseconds.

Comment: Have you determined that Integer.parseInt(x, 16) is actually using "too many resources" for your intended purpose (and identified what said "resources" actually are...?).

Comment: @NeilCoffey In my case, this will be a load on the garbage collector, since the conversion to String requires the creation of an array

Comment: "convert from hexadecimal to decimal java" makes sense if your input is in character format, and you want the output to be in character format.  But, your example code doesn't show or otherwise indicate that is the case. Note I deleted both occurrences of "integer" in the quote.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer This is the point that the Integer value is in the hexadecimal system in advance, and I need to convert to the decimal system

Comment: If we are confused, it is because you are not telling us enough about what it is you are trying to do, or what problem you are actually trying to solve.

Comment: With your update, how would it convert a hexValue of 10?

Comment: `int hex = 0x10;`, `int hex = 020;`, `int hex = 0b10000`, and `int hex = 16;` all do *exactly* the same thing.

Comment: I guess they want to convert `0x10` to `10`, `0x16` to `16`, etc. for some reason, but it’s unclear how to handle hexadecimal digits greater than 9.

Comment: @TimMoore It's true. I'm already confused myself, but that's what I wanted

Comment: Suggested reading: [How to Ask a Good Queston](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Complete, Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  . The example you have given is sub-minimal and incomplete.

Comment: I don’t know what “ a full-fledged index for the array” means. What array? Why are its indices specified in this way? What should happen if the number provided can’t be converted this way?

Comment: I suspect this is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).   The explanations need to be expanded. The examples need to be expanded. We need more explanation of what is trying to be done. Where do the numbers come from?  If they are from a file, show code that reads the file. Show an example of the contents of the file. Show code for the array that needs to be indexed.

Comment: When you say you want to get the value '10' from `int hex = 16`, what value do you mean?  Do you want the value we call 'ten' or the value we call 'sixteen', both of which can represented by the sequence of characters 'digit one followed by digit zero'.  As others have said, you are confusing the actual number, which is fixed at sixteen, with some sequence of characters, which sequence depends on how you decide to convert the number to characters.

Comment: Why have you removed your code ?

Comment: Do you still want help with this? If so, you need to edit the question again. Go back, start at the beginning. Tell us where these numbers come from. Explain the problem you have with indexing the array with these numbers.

Comment: Your revision does not explain why you think you need the number `10` to index your array, or even what you think the number `10` is. Please show much more of your code: where the number comes from, and what you do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Hex, binary, octal, etc are all visual presentations of a number in a specific base. Any `int` is already in "binary."  It could be +5 (1) and ground (0) if you want to go that deep into it.

So converting an `int` to another base does not make sense unless it is for display purposes.

Or given a string in a particular base and converting that to an `int` so it can be used in mathematical expressions or data structures is also an option.

Per your comment I still believe you are somewhat confused about numeric representation.  But here is how to convert a `hex string` to an `int`. This does not handle signed values.

```
String hexString = "2A4";
 
String hexDigits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
int result = 0;
for (char c : hexString.toCharArray()) {
     result = result * 16 + hexDigits.indexOf(c);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
676
```

And let me repeat that it does not make sense to try and convert any `int` from one base to an `int` in another base, as int's are not really in any base at all.  `ints` are treated as `decimal` by the compiler and we talk about them as though they are `binary` because it provides a common and accepted way to describe them.

**Updated**

You may want to check out [Integer.decode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#decode(java.lang.String)). If you are reading in encoded strings with prefixes of `x,X, and #` for hex ,`0` for octal, and a non-zero digit for decimal, you can do the following.

```
String [] codes = {"0x11", "021", "#11", "17"};
 
for (String code : codes) {
     System.out.println(Integer.decode(code));
}
```

prints

```
17
17
17
17
```

Comment: I want to convert a hexadecimal integer to decimal to use it as an index to an array

Comment: There is no such thing as a "hexadecimal integer".  It's all just integers.  Just try using the number without conversion, tell us the result.  It'll probably be correct.

Comment: As I said, there is no such thing as hexadecimal integer.  It is just an integer and is best described as a binary value.  However, math operations treat it as decimal by default.

Comment: I need to convert a hexadecimal number to decimal like in the first example, but without using the String conversion. I know in advance that it is in the hexadecimal system, but I do not know the original number in decimal

Comment: @user22150393 "_I know in advance that it is in the hexadecimal system_" – What does this mean? Where are you getting this number? If it's already an `int`, then **there's no conversion necessary**. In fact, in that context, converting the base has no meaning. If you have e.g., `int d = 255;` (decimal), `int h = 0xFF;` (hex), `int o = 0377;` (octal), and `int b = 0b11111111;` (binary) then all four are the **same number** already. You could substitute any of the four variables with another in a mathematical expression and get the same answer.